# Set Accepted-Lang for Chrome Headless with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, http-accept-language, google-chrome-headless

Setting the Accepted-Lang header works fine with regular Chrome via ChromeOptions
`options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})`

I'm trying to switch to new headless Chrome, but apparently this option has no effect when checking headers on validator.w3.org. Can I change them in another way? Anybody knows if support for this feature is coming?

Using Chrome 60, Chromedriver 2.30, Selenium 3.4.3, Python 3.6.1 on MacOS

Using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

print('Start')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages':'en,en_US'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/check?uri=google.com#validate-by-uri+')
print('Loaded')

# Check headers in output.html file. Search for 'Request headers'
html_source = driver.page_source
file = open('output.html', 'w')
file.write(html_source)
file.close

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Or check headers with select
# WARNING: This fails with 'headless' chrome option!
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//code[@class='headers_accept_language_0']").get_attribute('textContent')
print('Element:', element)

driver.close()

print('Finish')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer, have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. 
- One guy on the google developer blog asked the same thing without any answers: https://plus.google.com/114670839725657997273/posts/aVrAivf9jXo -

I'm using at the moment a Linode server which is by default set to English, this way I was able to circumvent the issue (need English headers)

Please leave a comment when you found a better fix, thx

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible using the [Chrome-developer-protocoll (cdp)](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setUserAgentOverride).

You can execute cdp commands using `driver.execute_cdp_cmd()`.